# What is the purpose and function of the "Media Storage" application and the media scanner?

Tags: applications, media-scanner

I want to know what the purpose of the system app "Media Storage" and the media scanner is for and why for any reason a user would choose to not scan media on boot.

Comment: Explained here: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/209119/218526

Answer (score 5):

Media Storage, package name `com.android.providers.media`, is an implementation of [MediaStore](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html):

> The Media provider contains meta data for all available media on both internal and external storage devices.

It scans and stores media file info for quick access, and provides *secure* (`content:///` scheme, as with all other providers) URIs pointing to the files for access by other apps.

By default, Media Storage has a broadcast receiver `MediaScannerReceiver` that listens for `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED`, so media scanner will launch on boot. Such receivers are unlikely to be disabled by end users unless with root permissions.

Comment: Can you explain the purpose of either. You explained the function, what it does, but not its purpose, what it is used for in a utilitarian sense.

Comment: "It scans and stores media file info for quick access" - so that individual media apps would not need to scan folders manually for an up-to-date library (e.g. painful if you have a lot of music / adds music often); "provides secure URIs" - so as to comply with the overall security mechanism of recent Android versions.

Comment: I thought you were asking the question from a *power-user* perspective, since you asked "why users would skip scanning".

Comment: "It scans and stores media file info for quick access" (function) "so that individual media apps would not need to scan folders manually for an up-to-date library" (purpose) . When you add why it's needed, it makes a lot more sense (e.g., A car goes from A-B (function) to minimize time and effort needed to travel (purpose)). I don't have any perspective of how to ask a question if I don't know how something operates. You still have yet to explain the purpose of Media Scanner.

Comment: Yeah, guess I was still quite stuck in the "developer" sense I acquired last summer in internship. The stuff I wrote are mostly from memory back then too.

Comment: So any idea on the purpose of media scanner? Why is it needed if files should constantly reflect (e.g., in Windows Explorer) what is being shown in storage?

Comment: I can't tell you what Google was thinking when they crafted it, but only what I think is reasonable... Individual apps don't necessarily know that a file has been updated, and thus will not retrieve the updated info unless manually asked to (e.g. folder-based players). Media scanner provides a way to scan once and let *all* apps that uses MediaStore know the updated details (via sending a broadcast indicating the scan is complete).

Comment: The MediaStore is the database holding the meta-data for all the device files. And the Media Scanner is the service in charge if inserting each file meta-data into the MediaStore database. The files meta-data is the information about file type (audio, video, image, etc), mime-types, image-size, orientations, the file path, and a very long etc. This is the way developers can query such information when creating apps. So, for example, a gallery app can do queries to show lets say albums of only photos or videos, exclude audio, or show images of only a specific type, etc.