# /system/media Directory

Tags: security, file-system, media-files

First of all, I am currently learning about Android security and wasn't sure if to post it on the Android or Security StackExchange, either way here is my problem...

Investigating the content providers of a particular app, I found out that:

content://media/internal/images/media

could be queried. After querying it, I obtained the following files, 
/system/media/video/edge.png and /system/media/video/edge720p.png

My question is, what is this directory for, and what are these files used for? Is it dangerous that this path can be queried?

Thanks

Comment: Could you clarify if you're asking about the [media storage](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/173914), or the `/system/media/` path?

Comment: Those pictures must be wallpapers, built-in by your OEM or ROM developer. I don't think there is a danger associated with their discovery. They are meant to be discovered like other internal media including ringtones.

Comment: @AndrewT. The /system/media/ path. Thanks.

Comment: @IrfanLatif hmm, got it. Thank you. I was wondering if that path would have been used for something different.